# How to import images from project folder in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to import images in Intellij Idea. The images are located in the project file.

I have tried to read files using Scanner. The file were placed in same place like the images in the project folder.

Is there I different place to place the images?

```
import javax.swing.*;       // JApplet          JButton         JLabel          ImageIcon
import java.awt.*;          // Container            FlowLayout          Color
import java.awt.event.*;    // ActionListener   ActionEvent

public class ButtonDemo extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
    Container cp;
    JLabel sunnyLabel, cloudyLabel;
public void init()
{
    cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    cp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton sunnyButton = new JButton("Sunny");
    cp.add(sunnyButton);
    sunnyButton.addActionListener(this); ////////////////////////////

    JButton cloudyButton = new JButton("Cloudy");
    cp.add(cloudyButton);
    cloudyButton.addActionListener(this); //////////////////////////

    ImageIcon shades = new ImageIcon("shades.png");
    sunnyLabel = new JLabel("Take your shades!");
    sunnyLabel.setIcon(shades);
    cp.add(sunnyLabel);
    sunnyLabel.setVisible(false);

    ImageIcon cloud = new ImageIcon("cloud.png");
    cloudyLabel = new JLabel("It may rain! :-D");
    cloudyLabel.setIcon(cloud);
    cp.add(cloudyLabel);
    cloudyLabel.setVisible(false);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String ac = e.getActionCommand();

    if(ac.equals("Sunny"))
    {
        cp.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        sunnyLabel.setVisible(true);
        cloudyLabel.setVisible(false);
    }
    else if(ac.equals("Cloudy"))
    {
        cp.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        cloudyLabel.setVisible(true);
        sunnyLabel.setVisible(false);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Error");
}
}
```

Comment: It's probable that your images are in a different directory structure to your teacher's, so Java is not able to find them just by their name alone. I wouldn't usually recommend this, but given that you're just learning, you can use the full local path for the images `new ImageIcon("C:/the/path/to/my/image.png")`

Comment: From Jack: What happens when the code executes? Do you get a FileNotFoundException? If so, you should try using the absolute path to the image files.

Comment: thx<3 @Michael it worked. is there other way than writing whole path?